# Setting high value for Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I want a thread in my application to perform a task and after that sleep for a particular amount of time. I use `Thread.Sleep()` with a `TimeSpan` value as parameter. It works fine. But when I set a large value say 25.20:30:40 (25 days 20 hours 20 minutes and 40 seconds) it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx

Exception   Condition

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException The value of timeout is negative and is
>   not equal to Timeout.Infinite in milliseconds, or is greater than
>   Int32.MaxValue milliseconds.

Value of sleep time is read from a config file. While testing, testers set this value to a high value as mentioned above. What I am interested is to know what is the better way of making my thread not do anything for the time I have mentioned. (Even if it is too high.)

Comment: what is `25.20:30:40` ??

Comment: As MSDN states, it can be no greater than Int32.MaxValue milliseconds, and 2,147,483,647 will be something about 24 days and 20 hours. But are you sure you program will run so long?

Comment: this is just for test purpose. 25 days 20 hours 20 minutes and 40 seconds.

Comment: If you're setting a sleep time that is greater than int.maxval - are you sure what you actually need is to sleep?  That's a long time.

Comment: ideal sleep time for my thread was 10 minutes. In a production scenario we wanted the thread to sleep for few days till we fix a issue. So I tried testing this for a higher range of values.

Comment: Even a few days seems a long time.

Comment: Even a few minutes seems too long :D Of course, if you really really really want to sleep this long, why not run `Thread.Sleep` in a cycle? A day at a time, for example? :)

Comment: Out of interest, what issue do you have that "sleeping a thread for days" will solve it?

Comment: @pm_2 : the task in the thread was doing something wrong and we did not have an option to give a immediate fix. During this we had no option to stop the the thread or the service which runs this thread. So we thought if we can set a higher value (by changing config) and make it not do anything, after it runs next time would solve our problem.

Comment: @Shetty: Okay, that does make at least some sense (given that you don't want to change the executable, just the config). In that case, just use the highest possible value and be done with it. You simply can't set it to more than int.MaxValue, so that's your limit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation tells you the maximum timespan:

```
TimeSpan maxSleepSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.MaxValue);
```

This is `24.20:31:23.6470000`. If you need to sleep longer then you will need to rethink your design.

Comment: In fact, rethinking the design is appropriate even when sleeping for 10 minutes... That's work for a scheduler, not `Thread.Sleep` :D

Comment: @Luaan - Yes, I agree, calling `Sleep` at all is usually a mistake.

Comment: @Luaan,@Lee : We have a existing windows service where we have a thread doing this task. This is not a new design :)

Comment: I am agreeing to the point that in such cases it should/could be created as a scheduled task instead.

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives you the answer to this - Int32.MaxValue milliseconds.  Int32.MaxValue is 2147483647, which is 24.20:31:23 (24 days 20 hours).

If you're trying to wait for this amount of time, you shouldn't be using Thread.Sleep - for a start this means you've got a thread tied up for each one of your active jobs.  I would suggest looking into a scheduling library such as [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) instead.  This will allow you to schedule a job to run at a specific time, or interval of times.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something? You answered your own question:

> The value of timeout is negative and is not equal to Timeout.Infinite
>   in milliseconds, or is greater than Int32.MaxValue milliseconds.

TimeSpan value can't be negative, infinite, or greater than 2147483647 ms (Int32.MaxValue)

Answer (score 1):

Geatest value you can set is `2,147,483,647` as MSDN already stated that

> it can not be greater than [Int32.MaxVaue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)